# Class parameter as optional function pointer not recognised as function

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Tapping on a tableview cell segue you to another view. Once arriving on that other view I call a webservice to load data asynchronously.

As I wish to keep my cell class clear from network code, I want to define my webservice call in the TableViewController, and set a kind of delegate property of my TableViewCell on prepareForSegue().

```
///TableViewController
override func prepareForSegue(...) {
 dest = TableViewCell

 dest.getDataDelegate = getData
}

func getData(...) -> X? {
 ...
}

///TableViewCell
var getProductDelegate: ((...) -> X?)!
override func viewWillAppear() {
 ...
 getProductDelegate(...) //Error - Cannot call value of non function type    
}
```

If I get ride of the parenthesis around the type declaration of getData, it recognize it as a function, but then the class needs initializer. I am using storyboard so I wish to avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I guess I just have to unwrap it if it's optionnal

Edit2: Yhea, stupid error. My bad, posting answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it's optionnal, the property type getProductDelegate is not a function anymore.

A simple unwrap allow you to use it as a function, as usual:

```
if let func = getProductDelegate {
 func(...)
}
```